# 'AppDelegate' does not have a member named 'managedObjectContext'

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data

I have been following a guide on how to have values using CoreData in swift.  I have been having the error 'AppDelegate' does not have a member named 'managedObjectContext'.  The guide was using the Beta version of XCode, has this been changed and any ideas on how I can fix my problem.

```
@IBAction func saveButtonPushed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    var newName = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("SavedFills", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
    newName.setValue("Test", forKey: "name")
    newName.setValue("Test2", forKey: "password")

    context.save(nil)

    println(newName)
    println("Saved")
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it shouldn't have changed at all. The error says it. There is no `managedObjectContext` in your AppDelegate.swift file. If you follow a tutorial, there should be a `managedObjectContext` in your `AppDelegate.swift` file already. Maybe you've missed this step. If this isn't the case, you should either add one by yourself or copy it.

If you want to get a 'standard' `managedObjectContext` just create a new Swift-Project and check the `Use Core Data` checkbox during the creation:

```
New -> File->Project-> Master-Detailview Application-> Use Core Data
```

If you are new to CoreData and Swift, try the tutorial from [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift) about Swift and CoreData. It's easy and nicely written.

Comment: That tutorial explains it very well.  Thank you for the help.